# how to solve problem with infinite packet dependency

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies, parrotsec

I have been installing ParrotOS (Debian) for about a year now on my computer and this problem has been occurring. I have a problem with package dependencies in relation to the package version that is simply unable to resolve. As you can see below, every time I try to use commands to install any package `apt install`, when I try to remove a package `apt remove` or simply upgrade my packages `apt upgrade`, it stops and shows several packages with dependency problems because of your version

```bsh
Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências não satisfeitas:
 cpp-9 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 g++-9 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 gcc-9 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
         Depende: libgcc-9-dev (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 lib32gcc1 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 lib32stdc++6 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libasan5 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libatomic1 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libcc1-0 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libgcc-9-dev : Depende: libgomp1 (>= 9.3.0-22) mas 9.2.1-4 está instalado
                Depende: libitm1 (>= 9.3.0-22) mas 9.2.1-4 está instalado
                Depende: libatomic1 (>= 9.3.0-22) mas 9.2.1-4 está instalado
                Depende: libasan5 (>= 9.3.0-22) mas 9.2.1-4 está instalado
                Depende: liblsan0 (>= 9.3.0-22) mas 9.2.1-4 está instalado
                Depende: libtsan0 (>= 9.3.0-22) mas 9.2.1-4 está instalado
                Depende: libubsan1 (>= 9.3.0-22) mas 9.2.1-4 está instalado
                Depende: libquadmath0 (>= 9.3.0-22) mas 9.2.1-4 está instalado
 libgcc1 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libgfortran5 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libgomp1 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libitm1 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 liblsan0 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libobjc-9-dev : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
                 Depende: libgcc-9-dev (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libobjc4 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libquadmath0 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libstdc++-9-dev : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
                   Depende: libgcc-9-dev (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libstdc++6 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libtsan0 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
 libubsan1 : Depende: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-4) mas 9.3.0-22 está instalado
E: Dependências não satisfeitas. Tente 'apt --fix-broken install' sem nenhum pacote (ou especifique uma solução).
```

I have tried every type of command you can imagine for months and searched for various commands and answers on different questions through StackOverflow, I even tried to update the gcc-9-base package to a newer version, but now other packages are asking for the old version, that is, I am stuck in this cycle dependencies.

I already tried to remove the packages and install some of them again to see if it corrected with this version with `dpkg` and Synaptic but it also didn't work

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? maybe a way to update all packages to the current version, or to update everything to a newer version like gcc-10? I need to fix these dependencies to be able to use `apt-get` again

Comment: Without knowing the *initial* reason the problem appeared, resolution is a bit random. Try `apt-get -d --fix-broken install` or at this point even `apt-get -d --fix-broken upgrade` . It will surely offer to remove a lot of packages. If those are only development packages such as gcc and cpp, that's not a big deal: you can reinstall them later. If it offers to remove packages like the GUI manager etc, just abort. Else remove the `-d` and proceed.

Comment: @A.B these two commands don't work either, they show the list of dependencies as well and then stop. The error started suddenly, I already tried to reinstall the OS but it always ends up showing up when I try to upgrade the packages

Comment: what are the contents of your /etc/apt/sources.list _file_ and files in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d _directory_?